# Forgot forking and now trying to fix

Tags: git, github

I forgot forking when kicking off my work. I cloned (without forking) the project and started working on it during the last few days. I have no repository on Github but would need to send my work to someone.

How can I fix this efficiently (there must be a way?!)?

I started again by forking the same project and now have it open in a seperate VSC file.
Can someone help me and explicitly write down all steps that I should do?

I found this advice on google, but have not managed to make it work. I don't know where I can find the "`<URL of your personal github fork>`". Can someone explicitly clarify how this works?

---

If you want to follow the development of the project you've cloned, by convention, we add a upstream remote in addition to your origin remote. So you have to:

Fork the project on GitHub.
Rename the current origin remote (that track the upstream project) with a new name like upstream.

```
git remote rename origin upstream
```

Add your personal forked GitHub project as the origin remote.

```
git remote add origin <URL of your personal github fork>
```

The idea behind that is to follow the naming conventions of origin for your personal repository and upstream for the project repository.

---

In my terminal I have this:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/Charlesvdb/react-interview.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Charlesvdb/react-interview.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/Particeep/react-interview.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/Particeep/react-interview.git (push)
```

Comment: What's your *question*? Is this supposed to be [self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?

Comment: Why don't you just push the clone to a new repo in GitHub, create a new branch locally, then when you've made a commit push the branch to your new repo and continue to work like that? In this case it doesn't matter whether you've forked it or not? Or if you really want to fork it, fork it and merge the commits with the fork.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with javacript programming. It's all about git as far as I can see, so I added those tags for you instead.

Comment: Mr Robot could you please explain that to me in full detail?

Comment: @Mr.Robot could you please please please help me with this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you help me please?

Comment: Help with what? The answer seems to be in the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just can't get it working, would you be open for a 5min skype/zoom call? you would honestly make my day

Comment: Absolutely not. The whole point of SO is that answers here help other people in the future, a zoom chat only helps you. Maybe read https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/

Comment: @jonrsharpe: ok then let's do it via here: 1) where should I be doing my "git merge upstream/master"? in my forked file or the one where I did all the work?

Comment: In a *file*? What do you mean? I'd strongly recommend running through the introductory materials on e.g. GitHub.

Comment: I mean in my forked version (Visual Studio Code). I am just a beginner and would appreciate your help on this specific topic vs referring my to introductory materials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'send my work to someone'. Create a GitHub repo and push your original clone to it.

https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

Once you've finished your work, make the final push and then send them the link to the repo. There's very little chance they'll care or notice whether forked or cloned in the first place, all they want to see is your code.